# Is there a way to create SimpleNamespace with boolean value false?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a SimpleNamespace with false value, but it is not working for me.

```py
EMPTY = types.SimpleNamespace(__bool__=lambda self: False)
assert bool(EMPTY) == False  # raises error!!
```

Is there a way to create SimpleNamespace with boolean value false?

Comment: If this can be done at all, it would require subclassing `SimpleNamespace` and adding the `__bool__()` method there.  Special methods are generally not looked for in the instance itself, as you're trying to do here, but only in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to give custom, "real" methods to individual instances of a class. In the original code, `EMPTY.__bool__` is not a method, but an ordinary function. You can see this by trying to invoke it explicitly:

```
>>> EMPTY = types.SimpleNamespace(__bool__=lambda self: False)
>>> EMPTY.__bool__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

See also [Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/). While it's possible - following the advice there - to make `EMPTY.__bool__` *behave like* a method:

```
>>> EMPTY = types.SimpleNamespace()
>>> EMPTY.__bool__ = types.MethodType(lambda self: False, EMPTY)
>>> EMPTY.__bool__()
False
```

that will **still be ignored** by `bool`:

```
>>> bool(EMPTY)
True
```

The implementation of `bool` looks up `__bool__` directly on the class, because it has no reason to expect an instance to have such an attribute.

Instead, we need to have our own class, with an *actual method* named `__bool__` that does the right thing. Thus:

```
class PossiblyEmptyNamespace(types.SimpleNamespace):
    """A namespace that is falsey when it doesn't contain anything."""
    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(vars(self))
```

Now we can test that:

```
>>> EMPTY = PossiblyEmptyNamespace()
>>> bool(EMPTY)
False
>>> EMPTY.foo = 'bar'
>>> bool(EMPTY) # oops, not actually empty any more.
True
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need to make a subclass. Dunder methods like `__bool__` are generally looked up on the class, not the specific instance, so setting a field on an instance will do you no good in this case.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

class FalsyNamespace(SimpleNamespace):
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

EMPTY = FalsyNamespace()
assert bool(EMPTY) == False
```